# Unix: ls -la reveals 4 files, one of which should be impossible, affecting other files

Tags: linux, unix, aix

Ive got a directory that contains a parmFile.  I need to read a text file by line and input the parsed text into the parmFile.  In my parmFile directory, when I type the list all command, I have the following:

```
bash: $ ls -la
total 8
-rw-r--r--    1 admin admin               0 Aug 26 12:57 -1
drwxrwxr-x    2 admin admingrp          256 Sep 30 13:45 .
drwxrwxr-x    9 admin admingrp         4096 Jun 02 11:22 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 admin admingrp            0 Oct 01 12:27 parmfile
```

Does anyone have any clue what the -1 file is? How do I delete this thing?

Comment: Apperently I can delete the file with "rm ./-1" but I still have no idea what this file is or where it came from?

Comment: How/why should it be impossible?

Comment: You could also have deleted it with `rm -- -1`; for this reason, `rm -- *` is better practice than `rm *`.

Comment: There are only two characters which aren't allowed in POSIX filenames -- `/` (because it's reserved for separating path elements), and NUL. Everything else is entirely possible. (This means that programs or scripts that assume that filenames can't contain newlines are broken -- often, dangerously so).

Comment: ...also, what do you mean by "affecting other files"?

Comment: Do you know why you have such a file?

Comment: I have no idea how it even got there.  Thats what I didnt understand.